# How to manually check versions to be processed in source table?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I use structured streaming and Delta to keep two tables (`A -> B`) in sync. Rather than a continuous streaming job, I use the trigger `AvailableNow` to run the update once a day only. `B` has a checkpoint tracking the progress from A.

When starting a batch, the sync is done automatically like magic, starting from where it stopped. Everything is running as expected. However, I would like to know from which version of `A` the batch is starting.

For example: `A` is at version 10, and `B` is in sync with version 7 of 'A'. This means `B` needs to ingest versions 8, 9 and 10 of `A`.

It's fairly easy to know the latest version of `A` using `DeltaTable.history`. However, how to extract the information from `B`'s checkpoint?